# Remove simple HTML-Tags from String in Oracle via RegExp, Explanation needed

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql

I do not understand, why my columns reg1 and reg2 remove "bbb" from my string, and only reg3 works as expected.

```
WITH t AS (SELECT 'aaa <b>bbb</b> ccc' AS teststring FROM dual)

SELECT
  teststring,
  regexp_replace(teststring, '<.+>') AS reg1,
  regexp_replace(teststring, '<.*>') AS reg2,
  regexp_replace(teststring, '<.*?>') AS reg3
FROM t


TESTSTRING             REG1        REG2          REG3
aaa <b>bbb</b> ccc     aaa ccc     aaa ccc       aaa bbb ccc
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Because regex is greedy by default. I.e. the expressions `.*` or `.+` try to take as many characters as possible. Therefore `<.+>` will span from the first `<` to the last `>`. Make it lazy by using the lazy operator `?`:

```
regexp_replace(teststring, '<.+?>')
```

or

```
regexp_replace(teststring, '<.*?>')
```

Now, the search for `>` will stop at the first `>` encountered.

Note that `.` includes `>` as well, therefore the greedy variant (without `?`) swallows all the `>` but the last.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I thought, ? stands only for "one or zero".

Comment: ? stands for "one or zero" unless when occuring after a quanitfier, where it stands as lazy operator. See: [Lazy quantification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Lazy_quantification).

Answer (score 0):

Because the first one and the second one are finding this match:
`<b>bbb</b>` - in this case `b>bbb</b` matches both `.*` and `.+`

The third one also won't do what you need. You are looking for something like this: `<[^>]*>`. But you also need to replace all matches with ""

Comment: The third one do _exacly_ what I need. I didn't understand, why. @Olivier gave the useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove HTML tags from string

REGEXP_REPLACE (teststring,'<[^>]*>',' ')

Comment: Although your answer is correct in the sense of obtaining the result expected by the OP, the OP was asking a why some of his code worked and some didn't work, he already had an answer, and was looking for an explanation. The explanation was provided 7 years ago, and your answer doesn't answer that question, and is posted in an old thread.

Answer (score -1):

If you are merely trying to display the string without all the HTML tags, you can use the function:
      utl_i18n.unescape_reference(column_name)

Comment: A late response but unescape_reference only replaces the tags for &lt;, etc. It doesn't strip out any other HTML (e.g. <p>).