# How do I extract value in PLSQL from between html tags

Tags: html, oracle, plsql

In Oracle PL SQL, I have this html file with the below comments tag.

How do I select the value between the comment tags?

```
<comment label="Comments">Text_to_Extract</comment></comments>
```

Thank you

Comment: Well it depends, is this part of a larger html snippet?  You need to post a [mcve].  You probably don't need PL/SQL just SQL.

Comment: You can do it like in this [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/sszN5OSt), but we have already answers in this topic, this for example: [handling HTML data in Oracle query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35457126/handling-html-data-in-oracle-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parsing HTML as if it were a string is generally not a good idea. But if you really do have a simple case like this, and you know your content is always formatted exactly like this, you could use a regular expression:

```
select regexp_substr( my_text, '<comment [^>]*>(.*)</comment>', 1, 1, '', 1 ) 
  from my_table
```

Answer (score 0):

Using xmltable in a SELECT sentence:

```
select comment_inside
from xmltable ('comments'
               passing xmltype('<comments><comment label="Comments">Text_to_Extract</comment></comments>')
               columns
                 comment_inside varchar2(200) path 'comment'
             )


COMMENT_INSIDE 
Text_to_Extract
```